# Powershell displaying all contents of array instead of stepping through one at a time

Tags: arrays, powershell, for-loop, concatenation

I'm new to powershell and I'm working on a script that opens edge and searches bing for a specific term. I have an array of terms, and a for loop that steps through the array. The loop works but instead of displaying one array item on each loop all items are being used. Here's my script:

```
#create dictionary
$diction = @("iphone","android","untidy","stew","camp","fresh","groan","warlike","party","bake","zephyr","play","lamp")

#loop
For ($i=0; $i -lt $diction.Length; $i++) {

    start microsoft-edge:http://www.bing.com/search?q=$diction[$i]
    Start-Sleep -s 5
    TASKKILL /IM MicrosoftEdge.exe

}

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Instead of 
http://www.bing.com/search?q=iphone
then http://www.bing.com/search?q=android and so on the actual result is 
http://wwwbing.com/search?q= iphone android untidy stew camp fresh groan warlike party bake zephyr play lamp

Am I missing something on how to display an array item in powershell?
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code like this.  Also, by using a variable for your command, you can use a debugger like ISE or VSCode to actually see what is being passed.

```
$cmd = "microsoft-edge:http://www.bing.com/search?q=$($diction[$i])"
start $cmd
```

Comment: Works flawlessly. Thanks for the tip. I'll accept the answer once it allows me to (you answered too quickly lol)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing powershell you should pipe **|** instead of that for statement
During the pipe the value passed is stored as **$_**
The Foreach-object alais is **%**
Basically is the array piped to a foreach-object

```
"iphone","android","untidy","stew","camp","fresh","groan","warlike","party","bake","zephyr","play","lamp" | 
    %{
        start microsoft-edge:http://www.bing.com/search?q=$_
        Start-Sleep -s 5
        TASKKILL /IM MicrosoftEdge.exe
    }
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```